# Multiple clients on Azure Service Bus, receiving individual messages

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-servicebusrelay

How do I fetch individual messages to multiple clients, from the Azure Service Bus relay, without having to have a namespace for each client?

Background:

I have a web service, which has multiple users, which are businesses. Not a huge number, but a few hundred. The users are mostly on NATs and behind firewalls, so I created a Windows Service to be installed on the users local machine, and that service listens to a Azure Service Bus Relay Service.

How can I deliver individual messages to these users/clients via the service bus relay? Do I have to create a new namespace on the service bus for each user? Or is there something smarter than that I can do?

Thanks!

Comment: VTC, I'm afraid - this is the kind of open question discouraged by the FAQ http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask. That said, if you look into topics and subscriptions, that will give you a way to receive only filtered messages. http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/service-bus-topics/

Comment: I added an initial question to clarify what I am specifically looking to answer. I do not believe it is very open-ended. On your suggestion: Yes, maybe subscriptions will solve it with the user of filters. Thanks.

Comment: Fair enough - the great thing about SO is that the community will decide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was answered well over at the Windows Azure forum on MSDN:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazureconnectivity/thread/235c1515-d507-4b78-9d84-9e04a49e038b